# Scripting in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, scripting

First Script and I need some help combining everything. I can obviously look up each individual one but i dont know how to put them all together. If you go to the page I am trying to script there is a table at the top that has the teams and the gameinfo that i cant seem to grab. I have researched for a couple weeks to get this far, hoping for a little help. Thanks

```
import requests
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("http://www.nhl.com/scores/htmlreports/20172018/TV010073.HTM")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

# WOULD LIKE TO GET ABOVE TABLE WITH ALL INFO AS WELL


#TEAM NAME
for td in soup.findAll("td", class_="teamHeading"):
    print(td.text)


#PLAYERS
#for td in soup.findAll("td", class_="playerHeading"):
    #print(td.text)


#STAT NAMES WITHOUT EVENT COLUMN
#for td in soup.findAll("td", class_="heading + lborder + bborder"):
    #print(td.text)


#ALL STATS EXCEPT EVENT COLUMN
#for td in soup.findAll("td", class_="lborder + bborder"):
    #print(td.text)

#LOWER STAT NAMES TABLE Without SH TOT
#for td in soup.findAll("td", class_="heading + bborder + lborder"):
    #print(td.text)

#LOWER STATS
#for td in soup.findAll("td", class_="bborder + lborder + "):
    #print(td.text)


#LOWER STAT TABLE With SH TOT
#for td in soup.findAll("td", class_="bborder + lborder + rborder "):
    #print(td.text)
```

Comment: You seem to grab **PITTSBURGH PENGUINS** so far. What do you want to grab next?

Comment: First, you shouldn't do as you do. You should find `table` and then iterate over it for searching all items

Comment: Solaman Raji- I would like to grab them in order all at the same time. Team Name Player name, stat names, stats, lower tables stat names and there stats. Then at the Top incorporate the Code Shahin wrote for top table so it is all one script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It will fetch you the data from the first table. There are three small tables within the first table:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("http://www.nhl.com/scores/htmlreports/20172018/TV010073.HTM").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response,"lxml")
table = soup.select("td table")[0]
list_row =[[tab_d.text.replace("\n","").replace("\xa0","") for tab_d in item.select('td')]
            for item in table.select('tr')]

for data in list_row[:1]:
    print(data)
```

Storing file is no big deal. Try this and get a csv output:

```
import pandas as pd

dfs = pd.read_html('http://www.nhl.com/scores/htmlreports/20172018/TV010073.HTM')
df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
df.to_csv("table_item.csv", index=False)
print(df)
```

Comment: Yes i did, thank you Shahin. How do i export something like that now? id like to know how to get into a csv or json file so i could import into postgresql. I would like it to be in the same script as all the info above eventually so i can run one script for all page data. Then automate it so i scrapes TH and TV (Team Home) (Team Visitor) then run through the season and games 0001-0073 so far.

Comment: Ok, Shahin. How do you store to file or postgres?

Comment: See the edit. Just run it. Btw, you can create a new thread for your csv issues if it has not been solved already. Thanks.